# azure json template Get suddenly error mesage "the template has specified a default value which is not present in the list of allowed values"

Tags: json, azure, parameters, integer, boolean

Suddenly my json-templates doesn´t work!
When I import the template into the ARM I get the error messages

***"The template has specified a default value which is not present in the list of allowed values"***

when I would to use a boolean or integer parameter. For a few days ago these template worked fine.
So I download for testing a template from github, with the same result!
Example Parameter:

```
"enabledForDeployment": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "allowedValues": [
        true,
        false
      ],
```

Comment: How are you trying to deploy the template? Where do you see this error? Please provide the full template and the parameters being passed to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Check out this quickstart template: [101-key-vault-create](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-key-vault-create) for cross-verifying the syntax. You can also deploy it to your Subscription directly using the **Deploy to Azure** button.

Answer (score 0):

these I've done, pls look at my description ( *For a few days ago these template worked fine. So I download for testing a template from github, with the same result!*)